# What does「DISC...ここなら隠し場所として位置づけだない」mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

A line of dialogue from a video game that I'm trying to translate. From what I have gathered, DISC...ここなら隠し場所として位置づけだない is referring to a disc and a hiding spot. What would be a good translation that makes sense in English and keeps the meaning?

Comment: I think you misheard ここなら隠し場所として**うってつけ**だな.

Comment: https://jojogame.bngames.net/images/special/03/03.jpg